# How can I delete the token when the user log out?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I made a **UserController** which generats an ***accessToken*** when a user registered succesfully on a page.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Login Method: in here we call Auth::attempt with the credentials the user supplied. 
     * If authentication is successful, we create access tokens and return them to the user. 
     * This access token is what the user would always send along with all API calls to have access to the APIs.
     * Register Method: like the login method, we validated the user information, 
     * created an account for the user and generated an access token for the user.
     */
    
    public function login()
        {
            $credentials = [
                'email' => request('email'), 
                'password' => request('password')
            ];

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                $success['token'] = Auth::user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

                return response()->json(['success' => $success]);
            }

            $status = 401;
            $response = ['error' => 'Unauthorized'];

            return response()->json($response, $status);
        }

        public function register(Request $request)
        {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
            }

            $input = $request->all();
            $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

            $user = User::create($input);
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            $success['name'] = $user->name;

            return response()->json(['success' => $success]);
        }

        public function getDetails()
        {
            return response()->json(['success' => Auth::user()]);
        }
}
```

My problem is that I want to remove the token when the user logs out but I dont know how to remove the access token from the user.

**logout** function in my **UserController**

```
 public function logout() 
        {
            Auth::user()->tokens->each(function($token, $key) {
                $token->delete();
            });
        
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Logged out successfully!',
                'status_code' => 200
            ], 200);
        }
```

When I test it with **postman** with the **GET** route: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout. Am I missing something?

---

UPDATE

Here s my **api.php** file:

```
Route::resource('categories', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController');

Route::post('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@register');
Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@login');


/**
 * We can group the routes we need auth for
 * under common middleware. It secures our routes
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){

 Route::get('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@logout');
});
```

I am testing it in postman using the route: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout and passing the Bearer token, which I get from the login request, as a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be POST Request instead of GET request, because your deleting/making change to the database.

The route should look like this:

```
Route::POST('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@logout')->middleware('auth:api');
```

And the logout method in in `UserController` should be.

```
public function logout()
 {
     auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
         $token->delete();
     });
     return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Logged out successfully!',
            'status_code' => 200
        ], 200);
 }
```

Comment: **Error: Call to a member function token() on null**, or nil object tokens. Didn´t work for me

Comment: It probably because your logout request doesn't include the token. When sending the logout request  make sure you pass the token.

Comment: I passed it in postman using the Authorization key and Bearer TOKEN as value.

Comment: Try this way. under  Authorization->Type-> select Bear Token and in the Token field just past only the access_token

Comment: Also make sure the logout route is protected with auth middleware. Because the user must be logged in first before login out. I update the logout Route on my answer.

Comment: I updated my question. It is under auth:middleware to protect the route.

Comment: Do not revoke the token, because each time a user login a new token will be created and when a user logout the created token will be set to Revoked(1). it will not delete the token in the database. Now Image how big the table will gets.

Comment: I see but when dong this it deletes all tokens from all users in the databse.

Comment: I think your approach is better regarding the fact that the database can get really big in some cases. But deleting all tokens is a bad idea or not? It should only delete the token from the user who logged out

Comment: This will delete only the tokens of the current login user. It will not touch other users Token.

Comment: Ok, I tested it in postman and created two users in my table. When running the code above it removed both tokens. I replaced your for each loop with ->delete() and it delted only the token from one user.

Answer (score 1):

In your logout function, it should expire the token, not delete it

```
    public function logout(Request $request) 
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return response()->json([], Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

OR if you wanna expire all his tokens:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function logout(Request $request)
{
      $userTokens = Auth::user()->tokens();
      foreach($userTokens as $token) 
      {
           $token->revoke();   
      }
}
```

Comment: I tried both. **Error: Call to a member function token() on null**

Comment: @Preefix, please check the second function, I edited it

Comment: Do you have the bearer token already set for the request in postman?? and is Auth middleware applied to logout route?

Comment: Do not revoke the token, because each time a user login a new token will be created and when a user logout the created token will be set to Revoked(1). it will not delete the token in the database. Now Image how big the table will gets.